# Understand PHP code in the separately JS file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii

```
$(".btn-delete-news").click(function() {
    if (!confirm('Are you sure to delete ?')) return false;
    var idNews = $(this).attr('news-info');

    console.log(idNews);
    $.ajax({
        url:"<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('/news/delete'); ?>",
        data: { id : idNews },
        type:"POST",
        success: function(data){
            if(data == "1") {
                window.location = "/news/";
            }
        }
    });
});
```

In script upon, when i insert that script to view file, it working well.
But i cut them, and insert them to the js file, such as script.js => script run wrongly, it dont understand the code : `url:"<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('/news/delete'); ?>"` , i must change it to `url:'/news/delete'` .
Who can help me to js file which can run the code `url:"<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('/news/delete'); ?>"`.

ps: Yii Framework is used here.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: No on can.. a JS file can't have PHP in it. Unless you make it a PHP file with JS headers.

Comment: Php files can have JS in script blocks not vise versa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a nice solution would be to add a data attribute to .btn-delete-news and fill it with the target url so that in your JS you can read it out and use it as target url:

**PHP:**

```
<button class="btn-delete-news" data-target="<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('/news/delete'); ?>" />
```

**JS (with jQuery):**

```
$(".btn-delete-news").click(function() {
    if (!confirm('Are you sure to delete ?')) return false;
    var idNews = $(this).attr('news-info');

    console.log(idNews);
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).data('target'),
        data: { id : idNews },
        type:"POST",
        success: function(data){
            if(data == "1") {
                window.location = "/news/";
            }
        }
    });
});
```

You could do the same for the target location if you'd want to

Answer (score 1):

It happens because .js files are not parsed as PHP files unless you set your server to do so (not recommended).

Since PHP there is used just to build URL, you can pull off something much more natural by making a JS variable in your header/main PHP file. The variable should contain the base URL of your app:

```
var baseUrl = '<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl(); ?>';
```

That variable will be available everywhere, since it's in the global scope.

The change in the URL parameter is simple and it no longer requires PHP:

```
...
$.ajax({
    url: baseUrl + "/news/delete",
    ...
```

However, since you say your app works with just `/news/delete`, you probably don't even need the PHP/baseUrl parts...

---

Here is another suggestion if you're using more complex URL rewriting (thanks @MrSoundless).

You could define all those complex urls in the header, not just `baseUrl`, so you can have:

```
var deleteNewsUrl = '<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('/news/delete'); ?>';
```

And in your .js file, just this:

```
...
$.ajax({
    url: deleteNewsUrl,
    ...
```

Comment: This is another possibility. The 'not so nice' part about this is that the url is not generated by Yii which means if your urlrules change, you'll have to change all your urls by hand.

Comment: @MrSoundless What do you mean it's not generated by Yii? Look at the `baseUrl`.

Comment: Yii urls are parsed based on your url rules defined in your CUrlManager. If those url rules change, your urls might change. createUrl will create the right url based on those url rules. So using createUrl will ensure that you always have a correct url.

Comment: @MrSoundless Exactly which is why baseUrl variable is built using createUrl upon each page load. If you wish, you could recreate more complex rules by defining the whole thing, say: `var deleteNewsUrl = '<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('/news/delete'); ?>';`

Comment: Yeah but your url is created as 'baseUrl + "/news/delete"'. /news/delete is not always a correct url depending on your url rules

Comment: @MrSoundless Yeah, yeah, just updated my comment to cover that. Updated the answer, too.

Comment: That, indeed, would work. But since we love data- attributes we should use those :P (personal preference)

Comment: @MrSoundless Ahhh, if there was just a single solution to everything... ;)